# Button to transition between a minimized or maximized Menu, but :hover blocks menu from being minimized

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

As the title explains.. I have a side bar menu that can transition between a minimized and maximized menu through a click of the button.  In the minimized state.. if the person hovers over the menu.. it would expand temporarily until the mouse left.

The problem is because of the hover state.. it blocks the menu from minimizing until they move the mouse away from the button after clicking it.. but I cannot figure out any other way.  Any tips or reccommendations?

I have a very simplified JsFiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ygpsnxhd/

The menu of what I'm trying to emulate: https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/demo1/index.html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidemenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button>Expand or Minimize</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidemenu {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 200px;
  &:hover.minimized {
    width: 200px;
  }
  &.minimized {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get smaller immediately after clicking the button? When hovering over the button again after the mouse is moved out, the size still has to change, right?

Comment: @Snow exactly.  if i were to remove the hover it would minimize exactly how i would want it to.. but i need the hover over affect to be there as well.  Unfortunately the hover affect blocks the minimize affect because of it.  I can't seem to think of a way around it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper element for your menu, which sets the width and height and has a relative position. Add your menu toggle button as a sibling to your menu and give it a absolute positioning at the bottom of your menu.

**New HTML outline**:

```
<div class="side-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="sidemenu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
        <li>menu item</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <button>Expand or Minimize</button>
</div>
```

**New SCSS:**

```
.side-menu-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  .minimized {
    width: 100px;
    .sidemenu:hover {
      width: 200px;
    }
  }
  .sidemenu {
    transition: all .3s ease;
    width: 100%;
  }
  button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz8a01Lc/)!

Comment: this is great!  it's late at night already but tomorrow at work i will definitely check this out thank you so much!